# wifi connection on android through windows 10 wifi hotspot keeps dropping

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, android

My laptop runs windows 10 Pro 1703 Build 15063.483 and gets internet through Ethernet. To get wifi on my android phone, i try generating hotspot on laptop through connectify, netsh etc. The android connects with the wifi for 1-3 minutes and then disconnects. Then i have to keep connecting it back to the wifi generated through my laptop hotspot. I checked that the laptop's wifi connection does not seem to drop as seen in the app wifi analyzer. I tried static address instead of DHCP

But surprisingly when i connect my android to the wifi from home router, it connects rock solid and does not drop at all. Now wifi analyzer app shows that both my connectify hotpsot and home wifi are on the same channels 9-12. Can it be causing a problem? How do i change my channels then?

I want to diagnose why is this happening. Firstly, is it a fault on my laptop side or phone side? Secondly is it a hardware or software issue? How to fix this?

The wifi from home router is very slow. The internet on laptop through Ethernet is very fast so i want to make the hotspot work on laptop.